# terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (objective C)

Tags: objective-c, nsexception, nsnull

The program closes at Objective-c. Please help solve my problem.
Error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x115289cf0'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCcwg.png)

Comment: "-[NSNull length]" Somewhere you have an object which is `[NSNull null]` but you are doing `[myObject length]` on it which is not allowed (you may be thought it was a NSString object). You may not call it yourself (could be an hidden call), but you need to find which line exactly is causing the issue (use `NSLog()`, Breakpoints, etc.). Are you using JSON? Without that we can't help you.

Comment: Google "cocoa how to debug uncaught exception unrecognized selector sent to instance"